# Using np.size to get number of column pairs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a table:

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3
1,1,2
1,1,4
2,1,3
2,1,5
2,3,1
2,3,4
```

I want to use np.size to count how many times the values 1,1 and 2,1 appear (this pairs). So 1,1 appears 2 times.

I tried `np.size([table.column1,table.column2])` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use group by you can get what you are looking for

```
table.groupby(['column1', 'column2']).size()
```